# Setting a StateObject value from child view causes NavigationView to pop all views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an app that uses a StateObject in a redux-like pattern. It's been working fine - until I tried to implement a NavigationView with NavigationLinks that can be used programmatically.

Every time I try to send a "dispatch" action from a child view, it pops the child off the navigation stack. I thought perhaps the problem had something to do with where I was passing the enviromentObject, so I moved it from the NavigationView to the child views. No change.

Why are my views popped immediately? Is there some redraw triggering that I'm unaware of?

```
enum NavigationTag: String {
    case page1
    case page2
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var store = AppStore(
        initialState: .init(),
        reducer: appReducer)
    @State private var linkTag: NavigationTag? = .page1
    
    var body: some View {
        let splashNavView = NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Loading..." + (linkTag?.rawValue ?? "nil"))
                Text("Something went wrong. You shouldn't be seeing this.")

                NavigationLink(destination: Page1View().environmentObject(store), tag: .page1, selection: $linkTag) {EmptyView()}
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("page 2 view").environmentObject(store), tag: .page2, selection: $linkTag) {EmptyView()}

            }
        }

        return splashNavView
        
    }
}
```

Child view

```
struct Page1View: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: AppStore
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color.orange
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                store.dispatch(.floatingView(action: .setSize(width: 414, height: 590)))
            })
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Switch to a `LazyVStack` vs `VStack`

Comment: @loremipsum Doesn't appear to change anything. Still getting the same result.

Comment: It is known that SwiftUI preloads `NavigationLink`s there are a ton of questions about it in SO using `List` `LazyVStack` is supposed to prevent it but some solutions call for a custom `LazyView`

Comment: Try putting the LazyVStack in a ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mocking up a Store where dispatches mutates a root @Published state that directly fires ObjectWillChange, I can replicate your popping behavior. If I separate state mutation from ObjectWillChange by using CurrentValueSubject or nesting an ObservableObject, NavigationLink performs exactly as desired.

I'd suggest decoupling a global root state firing from mandatorily marking all views as dirty. That way you can use a diffing mechanism to trigger that yourself.

That said, maybe there's a workaround re: @loremipsum comment. I am unfamiliar with that as I work with NavigationView in macOS multi-pane only, where I find it very reliable.

#### Edit: Example

Given your Q in the comment, here is a rough demo that keeps your root state on an @Published property.

That lets you pass your old store into the environment and use it as normal for views that you're OK with diffing for every possible state mutation.

Mock store & container

```swift
class Store: ObservableObject {
    @Published var state = RootState()
}


struct RootState {
    var nav: NavTag = .page1
    var other: Int = 1
}

class Container: ObservableObject {
    let store = Store()

    func makeNavVM() -> NavVM {
        NavVM(store)
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var container = Container()
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView(vm: container.makeNavVM())
            .environmentObject(container.store)
            .environmentObject(container)
    }
}
```

Navigation

```swift
class NavVM: ObservableObject {
    
    init(_ root: Store) {
        self.root = root
        root.$state
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] state in
                guard let self = self,
                      state.nav != self.tag else { return }
                self.tag = state.nav
            }
            .store(in: &subs)
    }
    
    @Published private(set) var tag: NavTag = .page1
    private var subs = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private weak var root: Store?
    
    func navigate(to tag: NavTag?) {
        guard let tag = tag else { return }
        root?.state.nav = tag
    }
}

enum NavTag: String {
    case page1
    case page2
    
    var color: Color {
        switch self {
            case .page1: return .pink
            case .page2: return .yellow
        }
    }
    
    var label: String {
        switch self {
            case .page1: return "Page 1"
            case .page2: return "Page 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm: NavVM

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Your navigation view")
                NavigationButton(tag: .page1)
                NavigationButton(tag: .page2)

            }
        }
        .environmentObject(vm)
    }
}


struct Child: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var color: Color
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button { store.state.other += 1 } label: {
                ZStack {
                    color
                    Text("Press to mutate state \(store.state.other)")
                }
            }
            NavigationLink("Go to page not in NavTag or state", destination: Child(color: .green))
        }
    }
}


/// On its own the Link-in-own-view-encapsulation
/// worked on first screen w/o navigation,
/// but once navigated the view hierarchy will pop
/// unless you stop state updates at the top of the hierarchy
struct NavigationButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navVM: NavVM
    var tag: NavTag
    
    var neveractuallynil: Binding<NavTag?> {
        Binding<NavTag?> { navVM.tag }
            set: {  navVM.navigate(to: $0) }
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Child(color: tag.color),
                       tag: tag,
                       selection: neveractuallynil ) 
                { Text(tag.label) }
            
    }
}
```

The demo uses a view model object to partition updates, but you can use a Combine pipeline in a view, too. You may want to do other variations on this general theme, from the publisher you use for root state and a UI factory object.

Comment: Do you mean nesting an ObservableObject in the store as a property instead of a structs? I tried replacing the navigation struct with an ObservableObject but I'm getting the same results.

Comment: No. You want to isolate your root state mutations from affecting the top view hierarchy. I assume you have a barebones RootStore with one @Published state property, one function called dispatch, and some middleware. The idea is to put that into a container ObservableObject that NEVER fires its publisher from ANY Published properties. That top view w/ NavigationLinks needs to only diff to navigation state changes, not other state changes. You could do that via .onReceive or a view model that subscribes to root state updates but only publishes a slice of that state.

Comment: I built a few apps w/ roll your own redux in SwiftUI. To make it performant, though, diffing mechanisms were essential. Most states didn't require much integration in the root/upper reducers, so really it was just equivalent to CLEAN stores/interactors/use cases but with the need to "exclude" views from every update. So, for the loss of amazing logging and thread clarity, I now just use CLEAN in SwiftUI because it saves a lot of time by having state in separate ObservableObjects with their own Combine pipelines. At least for my medium apps and their state models, that works w/ the least code.

Comment: Thank you for this. The back button is the only thing still not working now. It's popping all the views. Do you know what's interfering with that functionality?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CLEAN architecture. I'll definitely check it out. Sounds like it's a way to break up a single store a bit. Might be better for SwiftUI for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in `NavigationView` - it resets your `linkTag` to `nil` at some moment that result in navigation stack reset.

The workaround is to separate your links into standalone subviews, like in demo below (tested with Xcode 12.5 / iOS 14.5):

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Loading..." + (linkTag?.rawValue ?? "nil"))
            Text("Something went wrong. You shouldn't be seeing this.")

                Link1(linkTag: $linkTag)
                Link2(linkTag: $linkTag)
        }
    }.environmentObject(store)
}
```

and links like

```
struct Link1: View {
    @Binding var linkTag: NavigationTag?
    var body: some View {
         NavigationLink(destination: Page1View(), tag: .page1, selection: $linkTag) {EmptyView()}
    }
}

struct Link2: View {
    @Binding var linkTag: NavigationTag?

    var body: some View {
         NavigationLink(destination: Text("page 2 view"), tag: .page2, selection: $linkTag) {EmptyView()}
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but linkTag keeps getting set to nil. I'm pretty sure it's related to my StateObject because when I remove the lines on child views that set values on it, navigation works.

Comment: I noticed that behavior on macOS multi-pane and used a binding to disallow setting nil values. In your case for a stack view, I didn't find the sub-view or non-nil binding workaround worked. The first active link would allow state updates without popping, but once navigated after any subsequent state updates would pop the nav stack.